# Prevent default on screen, but allow buttons to be pressed

Tags: javascript, html, button, preventdefault

I'm building a website in js/html/css. To play part of my game the user needs to press and hold the screen. This will default to highlighting the play area, so on click or touch events I want to use an `event.preventdefault()`. The problem then is that the user can not click on other buttons on the page.

Is there a way to both prevent default when clicking and holding, but also allow buttons to work as normal?

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this might work. Basically using a boolean variable to detect if an specific button has been clicked and then add a conditional statement to the `e.preventDefault()` so when the button is clicked is not affected by the `e.preventDefault()`

```
let isClicked = false

document.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
   isClicked = true
   
   setTimeOut(() => {
      isClicked = false 
   }, 100)    
})

function myPreventDefaultFunction(e){
   if(isClicked){
     // do something 
   } 
   else{
     e.preventDefault() 
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. I ended up adding some logic so that we only "preventdefault()" if the game itself is being clicked.

const controller = {
  keyListener: function (event) {
   if (gameActive == true){
      if((event.type == "mousedown") || (event.type == "touchstart")) {
        if (event.target.className == "game"){
          event.preventDefault();
          down = "down";
        }
      }